# What's the equation $\hat{a}|0\rangle=0$ saying?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vacuum

This is a well-known result of ladder operators, which obviously means that you can't remove energy from the vacuum. But what is $\hat{a}|0\rangle=0$ actually saying? How does it say the "you can't" part of the sentence? My best guess is "The probability of having such a state is $0^2=0$ ", but I'm not sure.

A satisfactory answer to this must contain the word "zero", since that's the only thing that is given to us by the formula. Sentences like "you can't do that" or "that doesn't exist" aren't good translations of what the formula is saying. The formula is saying that some quantity is zero, and my question is: What is that quantity?

Comment: Isn't it more of *you can't destroy particles that aren't there*?

Comment: But how does it say the "you can't" part? What does the 0 mean?

Comment: It says that with the fact that the operation results in 0.

Comment: See my answer to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112807/

Comment: My question is: How does "0" mean "you can't"? 0 what?

Comment: @PatoRaimundo As Kyle said, it means you can't basically destroy particles that aren't there. So you have two 'reasonable' options: either you give back zero, or you give back the vacuum $|0\rangle$ and the operation does nothing to the vacuum. If you see my answer to the question I linked above, you'll see why the choice $|0\rangle$ leads to a contradiction, so we're basically stuck with zero.

Comment: @JamalS I already saw your answer, but it seemed to me that you just demonstrated why it can't be |0>, not why it must be 0. Every mathematical expression has a physical translation, and "you can't" is too ambiguous for maths. Maths would say, for example, "the probability that such a state exists is 0", which is, as I said, my best (and only) guess.

Comment: "you can't" could be ambiguous for maths (having only physics degrees, can't say much what a mathematician would say in the matter), but fortunately physics is *not* maths & it is meaningful to say that something can't happen. Not sure what the disconnect is here.

Comment: Doesn't is say "There is no such state arrived at by destroying the vacuum state"?

Comment: There is no zero in those sentences. The formula is specifically saying that something is zero, and my question is what that is.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8602/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145418/50583

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula says that the result of applying $a$ to the state $|0\rangle$ (which is a physical state) is $0$ (which is not a physical state). Since we know that $a$ is the destruction operator, what this equation implies is that there is no physical state which has less particles than $|0\rangle$; therefore, $|0\rangle$ is to be interpreted as a state with zero particles.

We say that "you can't take particles out of the vacuum" because if you attempt to calculate $a|0\rangle$, you get something which is not a physical state (for example, it's not normalizable) or, if you prefer, something that has zero overlap with every other vector.

Comment: I liked the last thing you said, could you expand on it? What are the implications of a vector having zero overlap with all other vectors?

Comment: @PatoRaimundo: For any state $|\psi\rangle$ at all, the inner product of $0$ (not $|0\rangle$!) and $|\psi\rangle$ is zero. This means that no matter the initial state of your system, the probability to ever find it in the state $0$ is, well, $0$, so that state is inaccessible.

Comment: Great! That's the answer I was looking for. The equation is saying: the state $\hat{a}|0\rangle=|?\rangle$ is a function or vector that is just zero everywhere. Therefore, for any state, the probability that they are the same is $\langle ?|\psi\rangle=\textbf{0}|\psi\rangle =0$, even with itself: $\langle?|?\rangle =0$. So it's saying "the probability of the system being is such a state is zero".

If you could include something like that in your answer for more people to see, then I'll accept it.