# What does it mean for the Hamiltonian to not be bounded from below?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, unitarity

According to [David Tong](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/five.pdf). In quantum field theory if you quantize the Dirac field using commutation relations instead of anti-commutation relations you end up an unbounded Hamiltonian from below, page 109.

What does the word unbounded Hamiltonian mean physically? And what does it mean mathematically if the Hamiltonian is not bounded from below?
And why is a catastrophe for our field theory to have an unbounded Hamiltonian?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366209/2451

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123311/50583

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164690/2451

Answer (score 3):

Hamiltonians that are unbounded from below lead to instabilities of the physical system in question. Mathematically, it just simply means that the Hamiltonian (or crudely, energy) can take arbitrarily negative values; it has no lower bound.

There are different ways to look at this problem. Let's start *classically*, for a *free* theory. Here, it is not really a problem if you have a Hamiltonian that is unbounded from below. Things change if we consider an *interacting* theory. Suppose you have a system $S1$ with Hamiltonian unbounded from below and a system $S2$ with Hamiltonian bounded from below, then an interaction between these two systems will excite $S1$ to a higher-energy state, and $S2$ to a lower-energy state, *without* violating conservation of energy. But this can happen indefinitely, leading to an instability.

In a quantum theory, the above holds, with some modification. Even if there is no direct interaction between two different fields (one with bounded Hamiltonian, and another with unbounded), they can still be produced indefinitely from the vacuum, *without* violating energy or momentum conservation. Nothing prevents this process from occurring, so it must happen, leading to an instability.

Apart from appearing in the context of the spin-statistics theorem as you linked above, Hamiltonians that are unbounded from below typically appear when you have higher derivative Lagrangians/equations of motion. Read up [Ostrogradksy instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability). They lead to so-called ghosts, which are negative energy/negative norm states. Negative norm states, of course, do not make any sense in (probabilistic) quantum theory. Busting these ghosts from a variety of  effective field theories is an active field of research.

See also my answer here on a related question and more info - https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/473778/133418

Answer (score 2):

If the Hamiltonian is not bounded from below, the (positive) kinetic energy part of the Hamiltonian can become arbitrarily large while the potential energy becomes arbitrarily negative (not bounded from below), with the total energy of the system still being conserved. This will result in the creation of a catastrophic number of particles.