# How to understand "always create before we annihilate, not the other way around"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, soft-question

On the book *QFT in a Nutshell* by A.Zee page 61 writes

> *Always create before we annihilate, not the other way around.*  —Anonymous

But in [this Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139616/) we are doing it the other way
around.

So how should we interpret that phrase?

Comment: Who knows. Maybe the author means that the creation operators are to the left of the creation operators.

Comment: an annihilation on the vacuum is pointless?

Comment: In my 2003 edition the quote is at the top of page 64

Comment: @annav Annihilation of vacuum makes sense in the particle number operator. If we would not annihilate vacuum, the particle number operator would not give zero for vacuum. So in this case we must first annihilate, then create - not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, the statement probably means that if you want to have a nonzero contribution from creation and annihilation operators acting on vacuum, you need to apply the creation operator first, since $\hat{a}|0\rangle = 0$, in other words, you cannot annihilate if you have nothing.

In the question you link to, the situation is different, as that deals with the *number operator*. Since we want the eigenvalues of the number operator to give the number of particles in given state, we need the vacuum state not to contribute. Hence, the order of the operators is changed and we start by annihilating.

Answer (score 0):

That's a [proverb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proverb) in the beginning of Chapter I.8 (in both editions).

Zee undoubtedly included it in the book because it reminded him of the fact that an annihilation operator annihilates the vacuum ket: $$\hat{a}|\Omega \rangle =0,$$ while this is not so for the creation operator $$\hat{a}^{\dagger}|\Omega \rangle \neq 0.$$

The proverb is not meant as a rigorous mathematical statement that applies to all situations, such as, e.g. [normal ordering prescription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order), which seems to follow the opposite saying.