# Difference between kets $\left| -x\right\rangle$ and $-\left |x\right\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

While using dirac bra-ket notation for quantum mechanics, what's the difference if the minus sign is inside or outside the ket ? I know that $\left| -x\right\rangle$ and $- \left|x \right\rangle$ doesn't mean the same thing but I don't really understand the difference between those 2 kets.

Comment: $+\left| -x\right\rangle$ is the state of a particle at position -x, with phase +1. $-\left| +x\right\rangle$ is the state of a particle at position +x, with phase -1.  The overall phase doesn't matter, but keeps track of whether two states will interfere constructively or destructively. (you simply add coefficients of states, so opposite sign phases cancel out)

Comment: If you like this question, you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8602/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: The thing within the bracket |thing> can be anything.  It's just a label.  You can put a picture in there if you want.

Comment: @adipy that should be an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\def\ket#1{\left|#1\right>}$Each of those kets represents the state of a system. In quantum mechanics the constant multiplying a wavefunction is not physically significant (multiplying a wavefunction by a number does not change the physical meaning of the wavefunction). So if $\ket{x}$ represents a wavefunction completely localized to the point $x$, then by what I just said $-\ket{x}$ also represents a wavefunction completely localized to the point $x$, its just that the wave function has been multiplied by $-1$.

However $\ket{-x}$ represents a wavefunction completely localized at $-x$ so it really is a physically different state from $\ket{x}$, because the wavefunction is concentrated at $-x$ instead of $x$.

Answer (score 10):

In a nutshell:

[image: plot of wavefunctions]

With a couple caveats: what is plotted here is really the wavefunction $-\langle x\lvert 2\rangle$ or $\langle x\lvert -2\rangle$ (so actually this graph is highly misleading in one way), and the spikes should be thought of as delta functions. But this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with the bra-ket notation, we must be clear that what we put inside the bras or kets is just a label and not something we make math with, although good labels makes visualization easier. When you write $|x\rangle$ you are considering the state of the particle in the $x$ position. (There is a problem here that this is not an acceptable state, since it's not an element of the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, but we can ignore this subtlety for the explanation working with the [rigged Hilbert Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) $\Phi^*$, but I'll ommit this assumption). What comes next is the fact that in Quantum Mechanics, states are represented by [equivalence classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of vectors of the Hilbert space and not just vectors. Two vectors $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ are equivalent $(|\psi\rangle\sim|\phi\rangle)$, i.e., they represent the same state iff
$$|\psi\rangle=\alpha|\phi\rangle, \qquad\alpha\in\Bbb{C},$$
that is, if they differ only by a scalar multiple. That being said, we can see that although $|x\rangle$ and $-|x\rangle$ are different vectors in the space, they represent the same state in Quantum Mechanics, since in this case we have $\alpha=-1$. On the other hand, the vector $|-x\rangle$ represents another state, that is a particle localized in the $-x$ position, so
$$|x\rangle\nsim|-x\rangle$$
because they do not differ only by a scalar multiple.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a change of basis. Its like a finding a new set of base vectors after rotating a coordinate system in 3 space. For your example you have infinite base vectors not three. For the negative of in front of the ket its just like multiplying a base vector by some constant. -1 in this case. it would make more sense to write -1 times the ket then writing a |-1 x i>. Don't forget that |x> is a set of base vectors.